# Use parameter and display it in a correct approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
Display the value of variable named data (from state management) at the webpage Testtt.js

Problem:
I get two erros:

1.
When I apply url "https://react-1swlsa.stackblitz.io/Testtt/1" I get a error that is 'Cannot read property 'match' of undefined'

2.
The webpage "https://react-1swlsa.stackblitz.io/contact" it creates a strange url that is "https://react-1swlsa.stackblitz.io/Testtt/[object%20Object]"
I do not know how is it possible to do it when the variable is a number.

I don't know how to solve it and what part am I missing?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1swlsa?

Info:
I'm newbie in ReactJS

Thank you!

---

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import Contact from './Contact';
import Testtt from './Testtt';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <h1>Webpage</h1>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/about">About</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>

          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          <Route path="/testtt/:p1" component={Testtt} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Contact.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Contact extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  state = {
    isData: 1
  };

  render() {
    const { isData } = this.state;
    console.log(isData);

    return (
      <div>
        Contact <Link to={`/Testtt/` + { isData }}>Testtt</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Testtt.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Testtt extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  state = {
    data: this.props.match.p1
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        Contact / Testtt {state.data}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues, first thing to note is that the following code in your class:

```js
constructor() {
  super();
}

state = {
  data: this.props.match.p1
};
```

is the same as creating your state directly in your constructor like so:

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    data: this.props.match.p1 // this.props is `undefined` here
  };
}
```

when you try and access `props` inside of the constructor, you must pass `props` from the constructor to your `super()` call, otherwise `this.props` will be `undefined`:

You can pass through `props` into your `super()` call like so:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
```

this way you can access `this.props` in your class field `state` object. Another option is to completely remove the `constructor() {}`, which has the same default behaviour as the above constructor that passes its arguments to the `super()` call.

Next you need to use `this.props.match.params.p1` not `this.props.match.p1` as `p1` exists on the `params` object of the match. You also need to use `this.state.data` inside of your `render()` method for `Testtt`, and the state belongs on your component instance (ie: `this`)

Lastly:

```js
`/Testtt/` + { isData }
```

performs string concatenation between the string`/Testtt/` and the *object* `{isData}` (this is shorthand for the object `{isData: isData}`). Since you're already inside a JSX expression created by the already opened `{  }`, your `{}` is interpreted as a JavaScript object and not an ebmeded expression. You can instead concatenate your string directly (or interpolate using template literals):

```js
`/Testtt/${isData}`
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I have applied the new code and suddenly I get another error message that is "Error in /~/src/Testtt.js (26:15)
state is not defined" (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-up4uax?file=src%2FTesttt.js)

Comment: I have used state.data syntax before and I do not know what is the difference in this context.

Comment: @What'sUP oh yes, I forgot to add that to the answer, it should be `this.state.data`

Comment: New solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fsmnt5?file=src%2FTesttt.js